# How to typeset aligned equation with annotations in amsart class?

Tags: equations, align, amsart

I wish to typeset something like this in `amsart` class:

[image]

However, since `\hfill` doesn't work in `align` environment, I didn't find a nice way to write this. Below is a cumbersome method that requires manually adjust some lengths:

```
\begin{align*}
    \hspace{.35\linewidth}
    A &= BB &\hspace{.25\linewidth}(\text{Due to E...})\\
      &= CCC &\hspace{.25\linewidth}(\text{Due to FF...})\\
      &= DDDD &\hspace{.25\linewidth}(\text{Due to GGG...})
\end{align*}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

---

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} % Doesn't work
    A &= BB \hfill \text{(Due to ...)}\\
      &= CCC \hfill \text{(Due to ...)}\\
      &= DDDD \hfill \text{(Due to ...)}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    \hspace{.35\linewidth}
    A &= BB &\hspace{.25\linewidth}(\text{Due to E...})\\
      &= CCC &\hspace{.25\linewidth}(\text{Due to FF...})\\
      &= DDDD &\hspace{.25\linewidth}(\text{Due to GGG...})
\end{align*}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Should the "(Due to ...)" strings be typeset hard against the right-hand margin of the text block? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I'd like to get the effect similar to what `\hfill` does in text mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might (ab)use `flalign`, but I'd prefer the realization in the middle or the one at the bottom.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{flalign*} % Doesn't work
&&    A &= BB   & \makebox[0pt][r]{(Due to E...)}\\
&&      &= CCC  & \makebox[0pt][r]{(Due to FF...)}\\
&&      &= DDDD & \makebox[0pt][r]{(Due to GGG...)}
\end{flalign*}
\lipsum[2][1-3]
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    A &= BB   &\qquad& (\text{Due to E...})\\
      &= CCC  &\qquad& (\text{Due to FF...})\\
      &= DDDD &\qquad& (\text{Due to GGG...})
\end{alignat*}
\lipsum[3][1-3]
\begin{align*}
    A &= BB   && (\text{Due to E...})\\
      &= CCC  && (\text{Due to FF...})\\
      &= DDDD && (\text{Due to GGG...})
\end{align*}
\lipsum[4][1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]